# fix absolute position overflow not showing in ie7

Tags: html, css, css-position, internet-explorer-7

I am building a design and have it pretty much done however an item I have positioned absolutely will not show the overflow in IE7. It works for every browser but IE7.. I'm not supporting ie6. The div/image will not show anything past its parent container in IE7. I've tried a higher z-index, overflow:visible with no success..  The absolute positioned div is in the top nav bar left of the first menu item.. should be obvious

The site is [here](http://modernlogic.co/pureblend)

thanks for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it in IE7, do the following:

Remove:

> position: relative;

From `.navbar-inner`

It's a bit redundant to have it on inner, because it's container is already set to a relative position (they are the same size/shape).  It will carry the same effect without it on the inner div, and give you the results you're looking for.

Comment: This worked, surprised I haven't tried this yet but thanks anyway!!

Comment: If you're experiencing z-index issues, I suggest referencing this article: http://www.brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

It will tell you how to work around the bug in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving .navbar-inner a higher z-index value than you have given to the absolutely positioned DIV.

I'd reduce your absolutely positioned elements z-index down to something like 100 and make .navbar-inner 101.